# activerecordで保存したデータのidの取得の方法を教えてください

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

`activerecord`で保存したばかりのデータの`id`を取得したいのですがうまくググれない(他の情報ばかりヒットする)ので教えて下さい。

イメージ

```
data = User.create(:name => hoge)
p data.id # 今作ったデータのID
```

また、今回の情報がヒットする検索ワードなどを教えて下さい。

追記

`data.attributes['id']`にて取得することはできました。
このやり方で問題はないでしょうか。

Comment: 例示されてる`data.id`で表示されるはずですが、`data.attributes['id']`で値が取得できた直後に`data.id`としても取得できませんか？

Answer (score 2):

手元のrails consoleで試す限り、 `data.id` のような形でもでidを取得できました。

```
irb(main):001:0> c = Company.create :name => 'hoge'
=> #<Company id: 4, name: "hoge", created_at: "2015-02-02 03:53:58", updated_at: "2015-02-02 03:53:58">
irb(main):002:0> c.id
=> 4
```

おそらくですが、どこかでバリデーションエラーが発生しているのではないでしょうか？

```
# nameが必須の場合
irb(main):004:0> c = Company.create :name => ''
=> #<Company id: nil, name: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):005:0> c.id
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> c.valid?
=> false
irb(main):007:0> c.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007ffc5b8646d8 @base=#<Company id: nil, name: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, @messages={:name=>["を入力してください。"]}>
```

idが取得できない場合、`data.valid?` の戻り値を確認してください。
`false` であればバリデーションエラーが発生しているので保存できていません。
`data.errors` でエラーの内容を確認してください。

> data.attributes['id']にて取得することはできました。
>   このやり方で問題はないでしょうか。

僕の場合、`data.attributes['id']`のような取得の仕方はしないです。`data.id`で取得する場合がほとんどです。
`data.attributes['id']`でしか取得できない、ということはおそらくないと思うので、根本原因を究明した方がよいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

まさかの万が一ってことがあるので。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def id
  end
end
user = User.cerate(nane: 'nazka')
=> #<User: 1, name: "nazka">
user.id
=> nil
user.attributes['id']
=> 1
```

idメソッド定義していたりしませんかね？
たぶん User.first.id('hogehoge'...)とかやると
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
みたいなエラーになって、本来なら from ...activerecord-4.1.9/lib/active_record/... みたいに、gemの中でエラーになると思いますが……。どうですかね。
※ できれば。使っているアダプタが何かのか教えて欲しいです。